# ASP.NET Core: Binding Dictionary<string, List<string>> to <select> strange result when nothing is selected

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My razor page has a property of type `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` which represents chosen countries by continent. I would like to bind it to the value of a `<select>` control.

```
//MyPage.cshtml.cs
public class MyPageModel : PageModel
  {
      [BindProperty]
      public Dictionary<string, List<string>?> ChosenCountries { get; } = 
          new Dictionary<string, List<string>?>()
          {
              ["America"] = null
          };

      public List<string> Countries { get; } = new List<string>
      {
          "Mexico", "Canada", "USA"
      };

      public void OnPost()
      {            
          Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Request.Form, Formatting.Indented));
          Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ChosenCountries, Formatting.Indented));
      }
  }

//MyPage.cshtml
@page
@model MyProject.Pages.MyPageModel

@if (Request.Method == "GET")
{
    <form method="POST">
        <select 
            asp-for="@Model.ChosenCountries["America"]" 
            asp-items=@(new SelectList(Model.Countries))>
        </select>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
}
```

When I GET the page, choose a country and submit, then the following is written to console:

```
[
  {
    "Key": "ChosenCountries[America]",
    "Value": [
      "Mexico"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Key": "__RequestVerificationToken",
    "Value": [
      "CfDJ...."
    ]
  }
]
{
  "America": [
    "Mexico"
  ]
}
```

The result looks ok.

However, when I GET the page again and submit without choosing any country, then the following is written to console:

```
[
  {
    "Key": "__RequestVerificationToken",
    "Value": [
      "CfDJ...."
    ]
  }
]
{
  "__RequestVerificationToken": [
    "CfDJ...."
  ]
}
```

Why is binder creating the token key and deleting the original key in `ChosenCountries` dictionary when nothing is selected?

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#dictionaries) the binder should look for matches to *ChosenCountries[America]* or *[America]* and not finding any source for these matches it should set the target's property `ChosenCountries["America"]` to null.

Answer (score 0):

As the document show, The peoject will match the paramter name first, If no match is found, it looks for one of the supported formats like `ChosenCountries[America]` or `[America]`. But in your razor page, IF you select an item and submit, check the request from in browser

[image]

It will show the dictionary's key and value, But If you don't select any item and submit, The request form will be like:

[image]

**Browser** will not send any information about the dictionary. So no matter how `model binding`  matches, It will not match anything, The `ChosenCountries` passed into your PageModel is a completely default value instead of a dictionary with `key = America`. you can write your code like this:

```
   [BindProperty]
    public Dictionary<string, List<string>?> ChosenCountries { get; set; } = 
        new Dictionary<string, List<string>?>()
        {
            ["America"] = null
        };

public void OnPost()
{  
       if (!ChosenCountries.ContainsKey("America"))
        {
            ChosenCountries = new Dictionary<string, List<string>?>()
            {
                ["America"] = null
            };
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Request.Form));
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ChosenCountries));
}
```

If you have multi `<select/>` in your razor page, I suggest you use `custom model binding` to configure.

Update==================================

```
public IActionResult OnPost([Bind(Prefix = "ChosenCountries")] Dictionary<string, List<string>?> model)
    {

        if (model.Count==0)
        {
            model = new Dictionary<string, List<string>?>()
            {
                ["America"] = null
            };
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Request.Form));
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model));
        return RedirectToPage("Index");

    }
```

Comment: Why does the bound ChosenCountries object contain a key named __RequestVerificationToken, as is printed to the console in OnPost method?

Comment: Because when the page load, It will automatically generate `<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="bababa">` to Prevent Cross-Site Request Forgery (XSRF/CSRF) attacks, when you choose nothing in `select`, It will add this `input` in your dictionary,

Comment: If you add a few more <input> controls to the form and submit without selecting a country, then all those inputs are present as keys in the ChosenCountries dictionary, not only csrf. So each bound <input> is actually bound twice - to some property declared as its bind target (asp-for) and also to the dictionary. Each unbound input, including csrf, is bound only once - to the dictionary. Why it happens? If you do select a country, then all is normal and there are no additional keys in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

`Dictionary<string, List<string>?>` seems like the wrong type. I believe you actually want a class to represent the Country & Continent relationship. A list to represent the available countries. A `SelectList` with grouping by Continent for the `asp-items=""`.

It's not exactly clear from your question, but I'm assuming you want the user to select multiple values?

```cs
public class Country{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Continent { get; set; }
}
// all available countries
public static List<Country> Countries = new ....;

// model
[BindProperty]
public List<string>? Selected { get; set; }

// view
var items = new SelectList(Countries, nameof(Country.Name), nameof(Country.Name), nameof(Country.Continent), null);

<select asp-for="Selected" asp-items="items" multiple="true"></select>
```

Comment: I need dynamic (unknown at compile time) number of multi-select boxes on the page. The dictionary structure works well except for the case when the user does not select anything.